# What would be the optimal way to replace the text in the project code with the t function from i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next

I was given a task to implement a localization for the whole mobile app on react native with i18next, react localize.

There is a lot of text in many files and so far the only way is to do it manually. Search through the files and then replace the text with the corresponding t reference to the translation file.

Is there actually another way of doing it faster and more convenient?

I made changes in quite many files to the moment. Sometimes thinking if there is a better way to optimize this process.

Answer (score 0):

If by chance your original language isn't English - You can search for characters in that language (using a regex). That will surface all the strings that are user facing (otherwise the code is in English).

Aside from that, I think regex's are your friend. You can search for ".*?" and similar to catch strings.

If you already have a translation file, then you could write a simple script that pulls a translated string, searches for it in project source files, and replaces the occurence with the `t()` equivalent.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah this script is what I thought about , but have no idea how to do this. So far from my research this cannot be done using just javascript , but with the help of nodejs, is it so?
One more concern is that this script might mess up some texts, so will need to get hands there anyway.

Comment: Node.js could be great for this, as your code is already in js, so you could read in the localization structure/map straight as code, and not parse it. Aside from that it's "globbing" all files in directory with extension .js, and then line by line - searching for the strings you read in previously.

To avoid errors - output a log of every change, so you can go over it afterwards and validate

Comment: And sometimes, straight up mundane manual work is the way to go - often seems longer than actually is :)

Comment: There are around 150 files with around 3000 words ( some of them are sentences , so this number may be less ). Looks real for manual work too.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all visible text (exceptions are placeholder and accessibilityLabels) would be in `<Text>` so you can probably override it with a higher-order component to use the existing text value looked up via i18n-next.  It's not perfect but it would be a start.

This would do the reverse of what you want (in that it replaces text with i18n keys) https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/rework/expo-app/src/lib/native-unstyled/hoc/withI18n.tsx.  But I used that along with my [hoc template](https://github.com/trajano/react-hooks/blob/master/src/hoc/withHoc.tsx)

(note untested)

```
import {
  ComponentType,
  forwardRef,
  NamedExoticComponent,
  PropsWithoutRef,
  ReactElement,
  Ref,
  RefAttributes,
} from "react";

export function withChildrenAsI18n<P extends Q, Q extends TextProps, T>(
  Component: ComponentType<Q>,
  _options?: O
): NamedExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>> {
  function useWrapped({children, ...rest}: P, ref: Ref<T>): ReactElement<Q> {
    const translatedChildren = t(children);
    const componentProps: Q = {...rest, children: translatedChildren } as Q;
    return <Component {...componentProps} ref={ref} />;
  }
  const displayName = Component.displayName ?? Component.name;
  useWrapped.displayName = `withChildrenAsI18n(${displayName})`;
  return forwardRef(useWrapped);
}
```

then add something like

```
import {
  Text as RNText,
} from "react-native";
export const Text = withChildrenAsI18n(RNText);
```

Then do a search and replace the text import with this replacement.